# How to create "who is accessing the page" in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make something, which is tell a user how many and who is (depend from username as example) accessing the same page with him/her.

Here's a little explanation about my case (to make it easier to understand).

for example :

1. I have 10 users.
2. I open home page (for example), user 1, user 3, or user 4 open home page too.
3. Home page will have a spot which is contain information something like

   - There are "4 Users accessing this page"
   - You, user 1, user to, etc. are viewing this page.

---

if there's simplest way to do that, i will be glad to use it, or if even i need to use library, what kind of library that i need.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: i don't know if my question is something like "Where to start" question for u,, but actually i already understand to solve my problem if i need to involved database on it,,,

but, it's not what i want, so if there any approach shared here, i'll gladly use it, i have my own solution, but i also want to try others..

i quite new in SO, but i don't know if asking something like this is forbid. 

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I am not so professional but i can think of only one solution for your problem.

What we have to do is, we have to keep track of user (i.e. which page user is viewing). We have to use a **database table** in which you will keep the username and the page name user is viewing.

Every time user changes the page, you will have to update the entry in the table.

e.g. If user opens a page index.php, you will search in database table for, how many users are there with the page_name index.php?, you can easily show anywhere on your page.

Comment: Hi amit, i also think about it, but, i wonder how much bandwith would take if every open a page we do update to database.

my other problem also when user open more than one page...

i've thought to use session / cookie, at the end i remember that session only work on our browser....finally, dead end :D

Comment: Hey Aradea, Yes session is not a appropriate solution, And i think if you are updating in database then there will not be any bandwidth usage, only server processing will be used(Assuming php and database is on the same server).  Database update will take processing but will be in milliseconds.
There are other options too. Like use Google Analytics API or You can use a file based system. But database option will be best among them.

Comment: Hi again amit, on progress to make a class of it, hope the result of benchmark not too bad, cause it will involve about 1000 users or more in a time. well, nice share, +1 worth it.